# How to achieve a fancy outline around an image in CSS

Tags: css

I have a div with a background image in it. I'd like to add a bubble-looking border around the div/image, like this:

[image]

Any ideas on how to go about this? Any help would be greatly appreciated. Here's a fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/1Loyyduc/

```
    body {
    background: navy
}

.mug div {
    width: 150px;
    height: 150px;
    border-radius: 75px;
    background: url(http://media-cache-ec0.pinimg.com/236x/03/5b/11/035b116cd6cfd398c0e779fcb8e73033.jpg) no-repeat;
    background-size: 150px 150px;
}
```

Comment: A containing element will form the circular outline, like this: http://jsfiddle.net/1Loyyduc/1/ You could probably play with the `:before`/`:after` to get the tail part..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here it is using `transform: skew();` and pseudo elements. Ideally it would have a transparent background, but I haven't worked that out yet.

[image: Screenshot]

Don't forget the numerous browser prefixes for the skew with the un-prefixed transform at the bottom:

```
-webkit-transform:skew(41deg,0deg);
-moz-transform:skew(41deg,0deg);
/* etc */
transform:skew(41deg,0deg);
```

[Have an example!](http://jsbin.com/kefafi/1/edit)

HTML

```
<div class="mug"></div>
```

CSS

```
.mug {
    width: 150px;
    height: 150px;
    border-radius: 50%;
    background: url(http://media-cache-ec0.pinimg.com/236x/03/5b/11/035b116cd6cfd398c0e779fcb8e73033.jpg) no-repeat;
    background-size: 150px 150px;
    position: relative;

}    
.mug:before {
    content: '';
    display: block;
    border: solid 2px #FFF;
    position: absolute;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    padding: 6px;
    top: -8px;
    left: -8px;
    border-radius: 50%;
    z-index: -2;
    background: #333;
}
.mug:after {
    content: '';
    display: block;
    background: #333;
    -webkit-transform:skew(41deg,0deg);
    -moz-transform:skew(41deg,0deg);
    transform:skew(41deg,0deg);
    height: 30px;
    width: 51px;
    border-bottom: solid 2px #FFF;
    border-right: solid 2px #FFF;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 10px;
    right: -16px;
    z-index: -1;
}
```

Comment: I have attempted numerous different methods to get the background of the triangle transparent (need to take a gap out of the border) and it's not proving easy! [Using a solid background like this](http://jsbin.com/kefafi/1/edit) isn't too bad.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a solution which is fairly close to the image (not exact) and very easy to implement. In your wrapper, add the following properties:

```
.wrapper {
    width: 160px; /* a bit bigger than the image */
    height: 160px; /* a bit bigger than the image */
    border:2px solid #fff; /* adjust stroke width as desired */
    border-radius:80px; /* must be width/2 */
    border-bottom-right-radius:0; /* this creates the triangle on one corner */
}
```

[Here](http://jsfiddle.net/nyv3oft2/) is that code being used in your example.